# SSRS Report Permissios in the database

Tags: database, ssrs-2012

How can I list the permissions of all users in my SSRS report server from the ReportServer database?

How are the reports stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
select C.UserName, D.RoleName, D.Description, E.Path, E.Name 
from dbo.PolicyUserRole A
   inner join dbo.Policies B on A.PolicyID = B.PolicyID
   inner join dbo.Users C on A.UserID = C.UserID
   inner join dbo.Roles D on A.RoleID = D.RoleID
   inner join dbo.Catalog E on A.PolicyID = E.PolicyID
order by C.UserName
```